# Cant change ui-view template from child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want display loginModal.html inside loginModal view after user enter main.login state, but it is not happening. Why?

**html**

```
<div ui-view="loginModal">

</div>

<div ui-view="content">

</div>
```

**js**

```
.state('main', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                "content": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/index.html'
                }
            }
        })
.state('main.login', {
            url: 'login',
            views: {
                "loginModal": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: this might be silly, but can you try using the url in main.login to be '/login' instead of 'login'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## "loginModal@"

You have to explicitely target the loginModal view in the root unnamed state.

```
.state('main.login', {
            url: 'login',
            views: {
                "loginModal@": {
                    templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html'
                }
            }
        })
```

## Explain PLZ

`<root>` is the parent of `<root>.main`, which is itself the parent of `<root>.main.login`. `<root>` here is an implicit state, which has your base page as template (roughly).

With named views, a descendant view targets its direct parent templates, unless explicitely told otherwise. Your `ui-view="loginModal"` exists in a higher ancestor state than `main`, so you have to explicitely target that ancestor.

For a detailed overview of view targeting, see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views